# How To Find and Replace Unicode String in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, find

I have a text file containing a list of Unicode strings. Let's say `list.txt` and I have another dictionary file `dict.txt` that contains a list of words (Unicode also), which needs to be searched in the first file and replaced with something else. However, my code is executing without error but not doing the find/replace properly.

### `list.txt`

```
राम गोपाल
राम प्रसाद
```

etc.

### `dict.txt`

```
गोपाल
प्रसाद
```

### `find_replace.py`

```
import string

# read the dictionary file of terms (each term in one line)
terms = open('dict.txt', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()

# read the file that contains terms to be replaced
original = open('list.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()

# initialize
replaced = ""

for term in terms:
    replaced = original.replace(term, u"")

print(replaced)
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: unicode aside, you have a logic error. in your loop you keep reassigning `replaced` but you keep using `original` so the output will end up being the original string with only the last `term` removed

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```py
# read the dictionary file of terms (each term in one line)
terms = open('dict.txt', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()

# read the file that contains terms to be replaced
original = open('list.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()

# initialize
replaced = original

for term in terms:
    replaced = replaced.replace(term, u'something else')

print(replaced)
```